# django type error cannot concatenate str and deferred attribute objects

Tags: python, django

In the code I am connecting to my database and creating a bunch of links. I am following the tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0d09mYsORs

with the code as is, the instructor is able to run the code. I am not.

I am unsure what a deferred object is, and what the issue may be. I have read the docs for a while, and am requesting some assistance while I continue to push.

The code:

```
def index(request):
    allAlbums = Album.objects.all()
    html = ''
    for album in allAlbums:
        url = '/music/' + str(album.id) + '/'
        html += '<a href ="' + url + '">' + Album.albumTitle + '</a><br>'
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

when I try and cast the Album.albumTitle attribute as a string, I receive zero content.

Comment: you should to change `Album.albumTitle` to `album.albumTitle`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Album` in `Album.albumTitle` should be lowercase, or else you are accessing the class, and not the specific instance you want.

Corrected code:

```
def index(request):
  allAlbums = Album.objects.all()
  html = ''
  for album in allAlbums:
    url = '/music/' + str(album.id) + '/'
    html += '<a href ="' + url + '">' + album.albumTitle + '</a><br>'
  return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: hahahaha you're kidding me of course! the lower case a. the damn album variable not the actual table class.

I'm going to go drink heavily while eating twinkies and crying!

Comment: Ha no problem, we've all made that mistake ;) And if the answers work for you on SO when asking a question, hit the green check button under the voting on the left - helps identify the right answer for future users. Good luck!

Comment: yep i gotta wait another minute and then it will allow me to give you the points.

Answer (score -1):

use your same technique as the line above it. change:

```
html += '<a href ="' + url + '">' + Album.albumTitle + '</a><br>'
```

to:

```
html += '<a href ="' + url + '">' + str(Album.albumTitle) + '</a><br>'
```

Comment: see I tried that, and when that happens, I get presented a white page with no content. That may be because my HTML was invalid but perhaps not, trying anyway will report.

Answer (score -1):

```
def index(request):
    allAlbums = Album.objects.all()
    html = ''
    for album in allAlbums:
        url = '/music/' + str(album.id) + '/'
        html += '<a href ="' + url + '">' + album.albumTitle + '</a><br>'
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

This worked for me, I was facing the same issue and following Bucky.As album is

Comment: That's exactly the same code as in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40940979/1816580). Can you explain how your answer provides anything new?